# Tensorflow: How to use tf.reduce_prod only across selected indices in batched data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm quite sure that there is a very easy way to do this but I was not able to find it so far

## Problem

I have two tensors.

One has a probability for each action across a batch. Thus, it has size `N times M` where N is the batch size and M is the number of possible actions. This is called `action_probs`

As my agent can do multiple actions, my other tensor has ones for actions that had been chosen and zero otherwise. This has the same dimension as `action_probs` and is called `action`.

I want to output, for each batch, the probability of choosing those actions. The probability for each batch is the product of the probabilities of the picked indices.

## Attempted failed methods

I tried to first create a mask and then conduct `tf.reduce_prob` over the whole thing like as follows

```
ones = tf.ones_like(action)
mask = tf.equal(action, ones)
action_probs_masked = tf.boolean_mask(action_probs, mask)
picked_action_probs = tf.reduce_prod(action_probs_masked, axis = 1)
```

However, as the boolean mask does not return a 2d array, this was not successful.
I tried next to loop over each index using `tf.while_loop` but the code became too complicated and filled with bugs so I was not able to continue.

## Example

Input

```
action = [[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0], [1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]]
action_probs = [[0.9, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5], [0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4]]
```

Output

```
output = [0.2,0.12]
```

which is given by
[0.4*0.5, 0.5*0.6*0.4]

If anything is unclear please tell me in the comments!

Comment: Can you give an example of input and except output?

Comment: @giser_yugang Thanks for the suggestion. I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask `action_probs` to 1 when `action=0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

action = tf.constant([[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0], [1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]],dtype=tf.float32)
action_probs  = tf.constant([[0.9, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5], [0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4]],dtype=tf.float32)

action_probs_mask = tf.where(tf.equal(action,1),action_probs,tf.ones_like(action_probs))
result = tf.reduce_prod(action_probs_mask,axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[0.2  0.12]
```